# Get content from a specific div that is in another page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

ajax and jquery newbie here.

Let's say I want the **current page** to only get div 3 content that's from **another page** and load it inside div 1, how do I do that with jquery or ajax? Both page are on the same domain name.

example.com/**current-page**

```
<div id="1"> </div>
<div id="2"> </div>
```

example.com/**another-page**

```
<div id="3"> </div>
<div id="4"> </div>
```

Comment: If both pages are part of the same website it would be a much better idea to use a server-side include over an AJAX request

Comment: `$.get("example.com/another-page/#3",function(data){//append div received as data})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of jQuery "load" method to load it (like this):

```
 $('#result').load('exampledomain.com #targetdiv');
```

**Please note there is a space between domain name and #target**

Comment: I've tried the code, it seems to load div#4 and the whole page from the url also. How can I make it so it only loads div #3?

Comment: Please check the updated answer which fill fix this for you.

Comment: It works. I'm just wondering. Does jquery load works by loading the entire page first, then it strips down whatever that's not in the selector.